# Let users filter a google sheet based database on a webpage

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a big database in google sheets (or a csv file). I have managed to put the database on a web page with google visualizations,  but now I am looking for a way to put some sort of drop down menu that users can fill in to filter the database according to their needs using the google sheet, where the filtered information comes on the webpage. Is this possible using google sheets in an html environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the Google Sheets REST api should supply what you're looking for.

For a full explanation see:  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/